# Which file is called or event is fired when we plug-in / plug-out power supply to the laptop?

Tags: power-management, cpu

Everytime I plug-in or plug-out powersupply the CPU frequency is changed to 'powersave' which results in reduced efficiency. I need to be on 'performance' all the time. I've made a small java utility which I use to turn my CPUs on performance. But this is kind of a too-much-repetitive process as I've to run the Java utility every two hours, whenever I plug-in or plug-out powersupply. Any idea where I can place the commands like this:-

```
cpufreq-selector -c 0 -g performance  
cpufreq-selector -c 1 -g performance
```

so that everytime I plug-in or plug-out powersupply then the CPUs are set to performance automatically.

I've Jupiter installed so I believe that might be the culprit. Uninstalling Jupiter is one thing that I haven't tried, however, I'm really interested in knowing what's the standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you plug in/out the AC adapter, the scripts in `/etc/pm/power.d` get called with an argument: "true" (if you run on battery), or "false" (if you run with the power adapter).

As far as I know the only package that ships with a "power.d" script that does what you say is [powernap-common](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/powernap-common), specifically its file: `/etc/pm/power.d/cpu_frequency`. Therefore the first thing to do would be to remove that file.

Anyhow, the default scaling governor in Ubuntu is *ondemand*, not *performance*. The *ondemand* governor is set by `/etc/init.d/ondemand` during boot. So you may either modify (or replace) `/etc/init.d/ondemand` or add a new script to `/etc/pm/power.d` in order to set the *performance* governor.

### New script to `/etc/pm/power.d`

So I suggest you to create a new file `/etc/pm/power.d/frequency-scaling` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
for f in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
do
    echo performance > "$f"
done
```

The give it executable permissions:

```
# chmod +x /etc/pm/power.d/frequency-scaling
```

### Modify `/etc/init.d/ondemand`

Just open `/etc/init.d/ondemand` and replace all occurrences of `ondemand` and `interactive` with `performance`.

### Notes about *performance*

You probably already know, but I must add that the *performance* scaling governor will make your CPU run always at the highest frequency. This means that often your computer will consume more power than required and will heat more than it should.

Instead, *interactive*/_ondemand_ gives you both speed and power saving.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the precaution. I really appreciate your knowledge about Ubuntu distro.