# How can I run a script when the power supply is plugged-in or -out?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

For some reason, my laptop's screen brightness does not update when I plug-in or plug-out the power supply. I've looked at quite a few solutions for that problem, but none of them seemed to work well. So, instead of despairing and giving up, I decided to try to turn this into a learning experience and see if I can't write a script that does it for me.

I tried figuring it out on my own, with some help from the internet, of course, but I'm pretty new to bash scripting and Ubuntu in general, so I didn't get far.

What I was able to figure out was that I can [find the state of the battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal) with

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1 | grep -E "state"
state:     charging/discharging
```

depending on whether or not the AC adapter is plugged in. I don't know if that's even useful, but it's kinda cool, and I didn't know how to use `grep` before, so what the hell, learning is fun.

Anyways, is there a somewhat clean way to do this? By "clean way" I just mean a way that one with limited bash script experience could comprehend.

One similar question I found that had a good answer is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346595/which-file-is-called-or-event-is-fired-when-we-plug-in-plug-out-power-supply-t), which says the following:

> When you plug in/out the AC adapter, the scripts in `/etc/pm/power.d` get called with >an argument: "true" (if you run on battery), or "false" (if you run with the power >adapter).

The problem is that I don't know how to access that argument from within a script. So, I guess it all boils down to a pretty simple problem, but I thought I'd post the question anyways, in case people had better solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`on_ac_power`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/on_ac_power.1.html) to run a script when the power supply is turned on or off.

Try the following in a terminal.

```
$ on_ac_power
$ echo $?
0              ## Laptop on ac power

$ on_ac_power
$ echo $?
1              ## Laptop on battery (not on ac power)
```

Based on this you can make your script as,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    if on_ac_power; then 
        do_something               ## Laptop on power
    else
        do_something_else          ## Laptop on battery
    fi
    sleep 10                       ## wait 10 sec before repeating
done
```

---

**EDIT:**

[**`cron job`**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) would be a better idea for running the script at a regular interval instead of using an infinite loop.

Save your script as `myscript.sh` and put the following content in it,

```
#!/bin/bash
if on_ac_power; then 
    do_something
else
    do_something_else
fi
```

Make the script executable from a terminal, `chmod +x /path/to/myscript.sh`. Open your personal `crontab` as `EDITOR=gedit crontab -e` and append the following line in it to run your script every minute.

```
* * * * * /path/to/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Is it bad practice, to have scripts running infinitely, or is that something that happens regularly and is built in to the system? I guess I was looking for some sort of trigger but if this works, then it's much less complicated than I had assumed.

Comment: @TheQZ: I think 'souravc' has given the basic idea..you can write your own based on this :)

Comment: @TheQZ Though it runs forever but becomes active only once per 10 sec (you can increase the check time) Look at the question how to [repeat-a-command-every-x-interval-of-time](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430382/repeat-a-command-every-x-interval-of-time-in-terminal/). Otherwise you need to write your own daemon program which is much complicated for the beginners.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Looks like that's what I needed.

Comment: A better way is to use udev rule as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/613741/ubuntu-15-04-pm-utils-do-not-look-into-etc-pm-power-d-anymore-what-instead.