# Car Media Server: Power Management Strategy

Tags: power-management, hibernate, wakeup

Got my mobile media server working in my car, but now I need to figure out how to get it to hibernate when the car turns off and wake when the car turns back on.

#### HARDWARE SETUP

```
             COMPUTER: Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop
WIRELESS ACCESS POINT: USB-powered Vonets VAR11N-300 miniature router
     OPERATING SYSTEM: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
    MEDIA APPLICATION: Plex Media Server
```

I wiped the old laptop, installed Ubuntu and Plex, then loaded movies on the hard drive. Bought an external power supply for the laptop that plugs into a vehicle cigarette lighter socket. The internal wireless card on the laptop is too limited to act as an access point, so I found a tiny, USB-powered router that could be configured as a wireless access point. All the components nicely fit into a storage compartment area next to the tire jack. I tested it on my road trip to Banff National Park and the kids were able to use the Plex client app to watch movies streamed from the mobile media server on their mobile devices.

The only problem I have is that when I turn off the car the laptop switches to internal battery power and keeps running until it dies. I would like the laptop to wait a few minutes after the external power drops off and then go into hibernation. I would also like the laptop to come back out of hibernation once the car is turned back on.

What would be the best strategy for handling power management services in this situation?

Comment: For hibernating when the external power is removed, you can set it to hibernate on low battery in the power management settings, and you can also set what low battery means, so you could e.g set it to hibernate when the battery is at 90%. I believe you need dconf-editor for this. There are also many other ways to achieve this, e.g. using [power management hooks](http://askubuntu.com/questions/590727/), to run the hibernate command. For coming out of suspend when the power is connected again - this is generally not possible, since the BIOS would need to support it, and most don't.